# Dot product of two vectors with different degrees

Tags: vectors

I have vector $\mathbf r$ which is defined as
$$
\mathbf r=(\mathbf r_1-\mathbf r_2)
$$
I need to calculate $\mathbf r^3 $ namely $(\mathbf r_1-\mathbf r_2)^3$ somewhere, so I obtain
$$
\mathbf r_1^3-3\mathbf r_1^2 \mathbf r_2-\mathbf r_2^3+3\mathbf r_2^2 \mathbf r_1
$$
Now I don't know "Should I write the angle between $\mathbf r_1$ and $\mathbf r_2$ in second and fourth terms?" namely:$-3\mathbf r_1^2 \mathbf r_2 \cos[\theta]$ or not?

Comment: By $r^3$ do you mean $(r\cdot r)r$? If so, jusing that definition with $r=r_1-r_2$ and expanding it out should give you the answer (I don't see why there should be any cosines showing up).

Comment: because dot product of two vectors is equal to $r_1.r_2 cos[\theta]$ and I want to see if such a rule is true about $r_1^2. r_2$ or not?

Comment: @Wisdom What is $r^3$ equal to if $r$ is a vector? Is it equal to $(r\cdot r) r$? In particular, you write $r_1^2\cdot r_2$. In this expression, what do you mean by "$r_1^2$"? Do you mean $r_1\cdot r_1$? If so, then this is a *scalar*, not a vector, so you cannot dot-multiply it with another vector...

Comment: @5xum I just know that $r$ is a vector which is equal to $r_1-r_2$ where these two are vectors also.

Comment: @Wisdom Sure. But what do you mean when you write the expression $r^3$? How do you calculate $r^3$ for a general $r$? Fr example, if $r=[1,2,3]$, what is $r^3$ equal to?

Comment: $r^3$ emerges when we try to improve our wave function by adding a $r^3$ term for variation method. Namely we had $Exp[-\alpha r-2 \beta r^2 ]$ and then we have $Exp[-\alpha r-2 \beta r^2-\gamma r^3 ]$. I don't have more info

Comment: @Wisdom If $r=[1,2,3]$, what is $r^3$ equal to? If you are unable to answer this simple question, then you have absolutely zero hope of ever answering the question you originally posted.

Comment: I think 36 be the answer

Comment: @Wisdom How did you reach this answer?

Comment: dot product of {1, 4, 9}.{1, 2, 3}

Comment: Where does {1, 4, 9} come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your result $\mathbf r_1^3-3\mathbf r_1^2 \mathbf r_2-\mathbf r_2^3+3\mathbf r_2^2 \mathbf r_1$ is **wrong**. You must make it clear which is a **dot product** and which is a **scalar product** in your calculations. You **cannot** expand the expression $(\mathbf r_1-\mathbf r_2)^3$ as expanding $(a-b)^3$, where $a,b$ are scalars.

Here is the correct way:
$$
\mathbf{r}^3=\left( \mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2 \right) \left( \mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2 \right) \left( \mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2 \right) =\left( \mathbf{r}_1^2-2\mathbf{r}_1\cdot \mathbf{r}_2+\mathbf{r}_2^2 \right) \left( \mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2 \right) 
\\
=\mathbf{r}_1^2\mathbf{r}_1-2\left( \mathbf{r}_1\cdot \mathbf{r}_2 \right) \mathbf{r}_1+\mathbf{r}_2^2\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_1^2\mathbf{r}_2+2\left( \mathbf{r}_1\cdot \mathbf{r}_2 \right) \mathbf{r}_2-\mathbf{r}_2^2\mathbf{r}_2\\
=\mathbf{r}_1^2\left( \mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2 \right) +2\left( \mathbf{r}_1\cdot \mathbf{r}_2 \right) \left( \mathbf{r}_2-\mathbf{r}_1 \right) +\mathbf{r}_2^2\left( \mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2 \right) 
$$
Write the above in the form of scalar coefficients, we obtain
$$
\mathbf{r}^3=\color{blue}{r_1^2}\left( \mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2 \right) +\color{blue}{2r_1r_2\cos \theta} \left( \mathbf{r}_2-\mathbf{r}_1 \right) +\color{blue}{r_2^2}\left( \mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2 \right) 
$$

Comment: Does the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: Thanks but what about $\mathbf{r}_2^2\left( \mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2 \right)$? I just know that I wrote $r_1 r_2 cos[\theta] $ for $r^2$

Comment: Please take a look at things I added